# Android - Weird EscapeUtil.unescapeString crash

Tags: java, android, json, unescapestring

I am getting a crash on receiving a JSON string from our applications server. We believe that when an entry has "quotes", there are **extra escapes** added.

[image: double escapes??]

In android, how can I determine if I receive such a string , and how do I fix it from the Android side?

Here is our current response string processing:

```
public String processResponseString(String responseString) {
    if (responseString.startsWith("\"")) {
        responseString = responseString.substring(1, responseString.length());
    }
    if (responseString.endsWith("\"")) {
        responseString = responseString.substring(0, responseString.length() - 1);
    }
    responseString = EscapeUtil.unescapeString(responseString);
    return responseString;
}
```

Also, logcat does not include the entire json string after the crash, so I cannot see the actual string that is causing the crash.

---

### Exception

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.optiisolutions.housekeeping.model.OptiiAPI.OptiiError cannot be cast to java.util.Map
 at com.optiisolutions.housekeeping.network.OptiiHTTPClientRetroFit$2.success(OptiiHTTPClientRetroFit.java:186)
 at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
```

### OptiiHTTPClientRetroFit.java:186

```
optiiClient.postRequest(event.getRequest(), new Callback<Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
     public void success(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap, Response response) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Successful response: " + stringObjectMap.toString());
          String result = (String) stringObjectMap.get(OPTII_RESULT_TYPE);
          String json = gson.toJson(stringObjectMap, Map.class);
```

Comment: What REST library are you using? If okhttp you can intercept response/request and substitute necessary values.

Comment: Yes, OKHTTP. The above example I believe is where we intercept the string.

Comment: Are you sure you are not escaping the string twice? Looks like the first time processed the quotes and the second time the slash

Comment: @WalterPalladino they are startsWith, endsWith, so I don't think it is parsing the same string twice.

Comment: The quotes are right, but if you scape the slash later will have to slashes. Just guessing.

Comment: Why don't you debug by attaching the debugger?

Comment: @rds I have, and there is no information, that is why this question exists.

Comment: What is EscapeUtil? Also can you post what crash logs you do have. Your "\" checks at the moment don't cover the example in your own question

Comment: how did you produce the json of the image you posted in the question? and, you are parsing json yourself instead of using a json library, is that right?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to parse `Map` in to `JSON` Like below code  by using JSONValue.

```
optiiClient.postRequest(event.getRequest(), new Callback<Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
     public void success(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap, Response response) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Successful response: " + stringObjectMap.toString());
        // For JsonValue you need to add one jar file .
         String json= JSONValue.toJSONString(stringObjectMap);
         Log.d(TAG, "Successful json: " + json);
}
```

need to add jar `javax.json-1.0.2.jar` in `gradle`  dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/javax.json-1.0.2.jar')
}
```

Download `javax.json-1.0.2.jar` Download from below link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjson102jar.htm

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your string. I'm assuming you want to keep the quotes. I could solve it with this simple algorithm, hope it works for you:

```
    public static String process(String s){
       String sep = "\\\\";
       String[] arr = s.split(sep);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       for(String str : arr){
          sb.append(str);
       }

       return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: this code will remove all backslashes from the escaped json string, which will make it impossible do unescape

Comment: @nandsito I might have misunderstood what you want to achieve. I thought you were looking for a way to remove the escapes. However unescaping should be possible since a string is not mutable and therefore I return a new string. You could always save the original string

Comment: your method may work for the code sample the OP showed, but if the server returned a line feed `\n`, your method would transform it into an `n` char

Comment: @nandsito Yes you are completely right. I changed the code, hope it works this time (ps this would only work if there are two slashes)

Comment: (after the edit) if the server sent an escaped reverse solidus, or backslash \\ your method would remove it from the response altogether. Actually i don't think this problem can be solved by filtering the input. I'm waiting for the OP to answer my questions so i can elaborate an answer